# Deleting a character pointer getting heap error

Tags: c++, oop, delete-operator, chaining

The following code is supposed to implement my own string class. Similar to if you were to create something like this `String s = "Hi";`. I am getting an error when it goes to destroy and gets to the part where `delete[] data`. Is says I am writing when I am out of the heap buffer. These are not cstrings so there is not a null character at the end of my string.

Here is my converting/default constructor:

```
    String346::String346(const char * oldString) : data(NULL), size(static_cast<unsigned int>(strlen(oldString))){
    data = new(std::nothrow) char[size];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= getSize(); i++){
        data[i] = oldString[i];
    }
}
```

Since these functions need to support function chaining I am going to put my both functions that relate to my problem one where if a `String346` object was passed or if a `char *` was passed in.

Concatenating function where `char *` is passed in:

```
String346 & String346::concat(const char * catString) {
    String346 newCatString(catString);
    concat(newCatString);
    return (*this);
}
```

Concatenating function where `String346` object is passed in:

```
String346 & String346::concat(const String346 & catString) {
        String346 tempData(data);
        size = tempData.getSize() + catString.getSize();
        destroy();
        data = new (std::nothrow) char[size];
        if (data == NULL){
            std::cout << "Not enough space to concatinate this string." << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            unsigned int index = 0;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++){
                if (i < tempData.getSize()){
                    data[i] = tempData.data[i];
                }
                else{
                    data[i] = catString.data[index];
                    index++;
                }
            }       
        }
        return (*this);
    }
```

My destroy function which does all the work for the destruction of an object is simple. It contains these three lines:

```
    delete[] data;
    data = NULL;
    size = 0;
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor allocates a `char` array containing `size` elements.

Then, your constructor appears to copy `size+1` characters to the array (I am assuming that `getSize()` returns `size`).

Therefore, the constructor code runs off the end of the array, and corrupts one byte past the end of the allocated array.

P.S. The `static_cast` is not needed, and only makes the code more obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your `concat` method:

```
String346 tempData(data);
```

passes a char * to your constructor which is not null terminated, so the call to `strlen` will go past the end of the string.

The next two lines also don't work:

```
   size = tempData.getSize() + catString.getSize();
   destroy();
```

`destroy` sets `size` back to zero, which means the rest of your method will not do anything.

You should try running this through a debugger and single step through it - you can then check the values of your variables at each step and make sure your program is doing what you expect.

Also, if you have a member variable that is freed in the destructor, you should look into the "rule of three" or "rule of five", to make sure things don't get freed twice.